# Show Extended Properties created via REST API in Outlook

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I've created an Outlook extended property for contacts with the REST API described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/extended-properties-rest-operations). This is the relevant JSON payload.

```
{
    "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
     {
           "id":"String {b06defca-5b03-4ee3-ba80-c5c9f49bea8d} Name MyProp",
           "value":"true"
     }
  ]
}
```

This prop is successfully saved and returned if I request instance of contacts with this extension via REST API.

```
contacts?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {b06defca-5b03-4ee3-ba80-c5c9f49bea8d} Name MyProp' and ep/value eq 'true')
```

So far, so good.

But how can I show this extension within the Outlook application, e.g. in Outlook for Mac v16.15 ? I assume, that I can add such an extension as additional column in the list view of all contacts. There are always columns named 'Benutzerdefiniert 1' ..  'Benutzerdefiniert 8' (in english 'User defined'). But nothing. Also nowhere within the huge (and BTW very good) Microsoft Graph docs I found any hint linking from the MS Graph REST API into the Outlook app.

What is necessary to have visible custom Outlook properties managed by the MS Graph REST API ?

Kind regards
Dominik

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using [Outlook web addin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/)?
You can create an outlook web addins in order to show the extension properties in outlook like this image below.

[image]

Comment: Is this 'Web Addin'  already finished and usable and do you have any download link ? Your link goes to the developer documentation, that means I have to code it by myself ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it by following the developer document.